# Using latitude and longitude information to assign locations to districts in Afghanistan

Tags: r, geolocation, geospatial

I am trying to figure out how to assign the locations of violent events, which are recorded in ICEWS, to districts in Afghanistan based on latitude and longitude information.

I went over related answers but they seem to focus on determinate countries and continents based on latitude and longitude information rather than sub-national administrative units. Moreover, the data sources that were recommended cover mostly Western states.

Therefore, I am looking for an approach to identify within boundaries of which district the geolocation of a specific event falls. My aim is to get a string character e of the district's name. This will be added as a new variable in the dataset.

Comment: *"I am looking for R package and/or data source(s)"* ... please reread what is [on-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), where that sentence specifically labels this question as off-topic.

Comment: It might be helpful to see https://kinglab.eeb.lsa.umich.edu/480/eda/maps.html. While it doesn't appear to include districts, it might be informative to see how they store the province-level data and apply what you already have about district boundaries.

Comment: Not enough. The site specifically states that asking us to *"recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource"* is off topic. Changing from *"looking for R package"* to *"looking for an approach"* does not change that. It's not uncommon for people to answer this type of question *anyway*, but most of the time I see those, the question has sample representative data and some attempt at it. For this, we're starting with nothing and it appears that your first research is asking a question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using sampled points from within Afghanistan:

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(dplyr)
library(sf)

afg_states <- ne_states(country = 'Afghanistan', 
                        returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  select(name, name_en)

set.seed(42)
sampled_points <- st_sample(afg_states, 10) %>% st_as_sf()

joined <- st_join(sampled_points, afg_states)

joined

#######################################
Simple feature collection with 10 features and 2 fields
geometry type:  POINT
dimension:      XY
bbox:           xmin: 62.42672 ymin: 32.72415 xmax: 71.09772 ymax: 37.57243
CRS:            +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0
         name    name_en                  geometry
1      Paktya     Paktia POINT (69.73146 33.93802)
2      Ghazni     Ghazni  POINT (67.96463 32.8195)
3  Badakhshan Badakhshan POINT (71.09772 37.57243)
4       Hirat      Herat POINT (62.42672 33.32973)
5      Takhar     Takhar  POINT (69.9511 36.91266)
6  Badakhshan Badakhshan POINT (70.64361 35.99117)
7       Balkh      Balkh   POINT (67.08079 36.678)
8       Balkh      Balkh POINT (67.14635 36.88358)
9      Bamyan     Bamyan POINT (67.32936 34.82846)
10    Paktika    Paktika POINT (68.55867 32.72415)
###########################################

mapview::mapview(joined) + afg_states
```

[image]